# How do I set a specific code to work once in 3 visits?

Tags: php

I have a code written by a friend, I asked him to insert a line that will make the code work work once every 2 visits or 3 visits, I have this lane that he told me is the right one but I forgot to ask him how to set it to work once in 2-3 visits.

```
$var = in_array(rand(1,1),array(1,1));
```

This is the line of code he said is the right one but unfortunately I don't know what to change, could you please help me with that, much appreciated.

Comment: All this does is create a code. How to manage and expire them is much more complex than a single line. Your question is too vague it needs more code

Comment: your question is totally unclear

Answer (score 2):

If you need to show womething to 1/3 of your users (randomly), use

```
$num = rand(1,3);
if ($num == 1) {
    // show
}
```

It generates randomly 1, 2 or 3. Chance that `$num == 1` is 33.3%.